# Acrescentar itens ao início de um vetor sem afetar valores existentes

Tags: c, array

Como fazer pra incluir 3 números no início desse vetor sem afetar os números anteriores?

Estou tentando fazer deste modo:

```
int main()
{

   int v[30];
   int i,x;

   for(i=0; i < 15; i++)
   {
       printf("Digite 15 numeros");
       scanf("%d", &v[i]);
   }

for(v[i+3] = v[i]; i < 18; i++)
   {
      printf("Digite Mais 3 Numeros");
      scanf("%d", &v[i]);
   }

for(i=0; i < 15; i++)
   {
    printf("%d\n", v[i+3]);
   }
```

}

Mas ao apresentar ele retira os 3 primeiros números e coloca os 3 novos números no final.

Comment: Explique melhor o seu caso de uso. Se você já sabe de cara que precisa de 18 itens, bastaria colocar os primeiros 15 na posição 3 em diante, e depois os outros no início.

Comment: estou tentando resolver os exercicios em vetores, que pede-se pra criar um vetor com 30 numeros mais que inclua apenas 15 e imprima eles e depois adicionar mais 3 numeros no inicio desse vetor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Após ler os 15 números, você deve move-los 3 indices. E só então ler os novos 3 números.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int v[30];
    int i,x;

    printf("Digite 15 numeros:\n");
    for(i=0; i < 15; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }

    printf("Os  15 valores inseridos:\n");
    for(i=0; i < 15; i++) {
       printf("%d\n", v[i]);
    }

    // Move os valores 3 indices
    for(i = 15; i >= 0; --i) {
        v[i+3] = v[i];
    }

    // Salva os novos valores
    printf("Entre com mais 3 valores:\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }

    printf("Os 18 valores inseridos:\n");
    for(i=0; i < 18; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", v[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Pela Ajuda, sua Resposta foi oque eu precisava!

Answer (score 2):

Se você já sabe de cara que precisa de 18 itens, bastaria colocar os primeiros 15 no índice 3 em diante, e depois os outros no início.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int v[30];
    int i;

    // Começa na quarta posição (índice 3)
    for(i=3; i<18; i++) {
        printf("Digite 15 numeros");
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }

    // Agora preenche as 3 primeiras
    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        printf("Digite mais 3 numeros");
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
    }

    // Imprime tudo
    for(i=0; i<18; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", v[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/3HaT5X

Comment: Pelo que entendi, no enunciado, ele pede para que se "mova" os valores do array das posições 0, 1, 2 ... para as posições 2, 3, 4... e não que salve direto nessas posições. Mas posso ter compreendido errado.

Comment: Pode ser, da [maneira que ele descreveu o enunciado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/306278/acrescentar-itens-ao-in%c3%adcio-de-um-vetor-sem-afetar-valores-existentes/306285?noredirect=1#comment621595_306278) pode ser uma coisa ou outra. Sem dúvida o código da sua resposta é mais útil, mas eu às vezes acho importante postar o óbvio.

Comment: Concordo plenamente com a ideia de postar o óbvio, haha. Realmente o enunciado deixa essa dúvida no ar. Parte boa é que aprende os dois jeitos

Comment: João é realmente do seu modo que estou precisando, porem ele retorna como saída os 3 novos números no inicio e transforma os outros em 1 2 3

Answer (score 1):

Usando o que você falou, devemos fazer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAMANHO_VETOR 30

int main () {

  int vetor[TAMANHO_VETOR], i;

  // Recebe as primeiras posicoes
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    printf ("Digite o numero para a posicao %d: ", i);
    scanf ("%d", &vetor[i]);
  }

  // Move as posicoes para receber os 3 primeiros valores
  for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    vetor[i+3] = vetor[i];
  }

  // Recebe os tres primeiros numeros
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf ("Digite o numero para a posicao %d: ", i);
    scanf ("%d", &vetor[i]);
  }

  // Imprime o vetor
  for (i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
    printf ("%d\t", vetor[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tem de mover de trás pra frente como fez o Ivanov. Porque senão você vai sobrescrevendo valores que ainda não moveu.

Comment: Perfeito. Não me atentei a isso. Valeu.